# wordpress website hacked; undesirable links and content added but admin panel looks fine

Tags: security, website, wordpress, web-hosting, hijack

I have a wordpress website hosted on plesk; right now i can see undesirable content that i never added and cannot be found from the admin panel.

Some of the menu links turned into porn words and even some article pages displays adult content.

I first thought my website was hacked, but i still have access to the admin panel and everything is clear there but it doesnt show the right content to visitors.

I first was alerted by a relative; and when I opened the website from my laptop Ii couldn't see the adult content(even after hard refresh and clearing cache) so he sent me screenshots from his laptop so I thought he got viruses into his browser, since it happened only there. But few hours later I could see it from my laptop, phone and everywhere! not only that but it got worse, the design was spoiled and there was crap everywhere; but still in the admin panel everything is just right.

I have never seen that! and I don't really understand what's going on I've searched and tried installing security extensions but to no avail.

Please Help! I've suspended the website to preserve reputation until i find a solution.

Comment: Files on the server have been modified. You’ll have to restore those files to proper working order.

Comment: @Appleoddity thanks for your reply! Has this happened to you before ?

Answer (score 1):

It may also be that your relative spread the virus to you through your communications with them?

I would contact your host provider and request that they run a full virus / malware scan on your website and the server it's on. They would (should) also have clean backups of your site (if you don't already). Also ask your provider if they can recommend any other security measures for your site.

For security, I recommend sucuri plugin for audit and hardening and wordfence for firewall. But there are other's out there that work really well.

GL